# How to change hierarchy of objects encoded in NSKeyedArchiver?

Tags: objective-c

We already have a game published that has save/load feature using NSCoding throughout the classes. We're now working on the next version but before we do that we need to refactor the code so it'll have better performance and it'll be easier to implement future features (this tends to get changed a lot).

The problem is after reviewing the new design. It has a different NSCoding hierarchy than the previous version.

v1.0
GameSavedFile (using NSKeyedArchiver) -> UserData -> User (parent of UserData) -> bunch of objects and primitives

v1.1
User (using NSKeyedArchiver) -> bunch of objects and primitives

v1.1 has a simpler and more straightforward structure. In v1.0, UserData is a subclass of User while in v1.1 we'll only use one class for all the User data.

It's easier and more practical this way. However, how can I port all v1.0 data to v1.1 without breaking anything? I've read that there's a setClassName:forClass: method but I think that only replaces the old class for the new class.

The cleanest and safest way I could think of is to check if the game is still using the old version (v1.0). If it does, convert the NSCoding hierarchy to a plist/dictionary then scatter it around in v1.1 code.

I am open for any possible suggestion/solution but I'll prefer a solution that's already available in the Foundation framework (if that's possible).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you should read [Forward and Backward Compatibility for Keyed Archives](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/compatibility.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001055-BCICFFGE), but it doesn't really address your issues here. (Read it anyway.)

Assuming you have not shipped v1.1 yet, here is my recommendation:

- Create a new save filename for v1.1. I often include the version number in the filename to simplify this. This makes it easy to tell which version you're trying to read before you open it. I generally like this better than Apple's recommendation of storing the version in the file. (Of course if changing the filename creates user confusion, or the user has control over the filename, then you should of course store the version in the file.)
- For v1.0 files, create classes like `V10GameSaveFile` that just hold raw data. Then use `setClassName:forClass:` to move the serialized objects to the dummy classes classes.
- Now that you have your structure in memory, convert it to the new object model, re-save, and delete the old file.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.

But is this a good approach? I've debated this issue with my boss. He keeps on telling me not to include any version specific code for save/load. Sure I can assign default values to null fields but when the hierarchy changed, I can't see why version specific code is bad.

Comment: Version-specific code in load is absolutely necessary in many cases. It should be isolated to the loading code so that you don't have to worry about it in the rest of the program, but there has to be some part of the program that knows the old schemas.